# Showing Error in all projects: ADT Bundle

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using ADT bundle for my **Android Application Development**

1) From last two days whenever I open my ADT bundle its showing error in all the projects (But I have no errors in my projects and I am sure about it). I tried to clean all the projects but no use... Sometime a restarting eclipse will solve this problem but after few days I am getting this same errors again.

2) Also In my **Android SDK Manager** some packages like Google API and system images in extras were broken, I don't know what to do.

I tried to clean my projects and to update the SDK manager but nothing solved my problem. Kindly tell a better solution to solve this problem. And tell me why these kind of errors are happening.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is the Error's are like (!) exclamation or normal error?

Comment: Do the projects mention anything along the `Problems` tab? I had a similar issue with Eclipse after a Java update ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891582/eclipse-ide-started-and-broken-cannot-find-any-java-classes )

Comment: Not ! its looking like normal error. I tried to change the android project build target in that I am seeking only 4.4W and L preview only I select 4.4W for all the projects then the errors have been disappeared. But I don't know whether this is a correct method or not. Also I am getting lint encountered a problem.

Comment: Kindly update ut ADT first then change ur SDK or update ur sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But for this kind of problems need more clarifications. Here is my few tips to resolve it. It may or may not work! But better give a try.

In each class or java file which place exactly it showing the error? For example for few it will sow error in **R.** file and the error will be **R cannot be resolved into type**. If you are getting this error try to import you package R. file (Like import com.example.R) will resolve issue. If you couldn't import then try to check the package name in manifest file and other layout files. Try to resolve all errors one by one in res folder then clean will help it.

Next check whether Eclipse issue or ADT issue. You said few things are broken in ADT i don't know what exactly it means but try to uninstall and re-install them again.

Try to update eclipse. You can do it by **Help->Check for updates**

If nothing helps follow the error which are displayed in **Problems** tab which present near console tab. Otherwise open it here Windows->Show View -> Problems.

Hope anyone will help you if not please follow the errors and edit your question with error. So you might get better answers!

Comment: 1) I tried to check the updates, but no updates were found,
2) I deleted all the system image and google api broken images in SDK manager and installing it again,
3) Also I tried to change the android project build target in the project properties in that I saw only 4.4W and L preview in the tagrger properties, I select 4.4W for all the projects then the errors have been disappeared. But I don't know whether this is a correct method or not. 

Also I am getting lint encountered a problem. Whenever I starting a eclipse. 

Thanks for this help

Comment: Then might be the issue with ADT. Something might have corrupted. Better you install all the api's and try it out.

Comment: Let me try this, anyway thanks for the reply. Will comment if the problem solved.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't help much with this but u try updating your ADT first. After that try updating SDK. If you misplaced this then you need to start from the scratch!

Comment: I deleted all the broken image files and I updated all the packages again and I set the target SDK as 4.2 in project properties. Now its working fine. Only problem now is error in content loading and android lint. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the vote! Lint errors are like guidelines to do better coding standards in android. It's up to you to take it considerable or not! But are those error restricting you to build your app?

Comment: No everything working fine, I am getting the error only when I am starting eclipse.

Comment: You can disable those lint errors by following the steps of Brendon. That might help you to move further!

Comment: Okay will try. And now, everything is working fine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble.
I completely remove Eclipse and SDK bundle; then, i re-install everything.
This worked for me.

Comment: But I cant do this, I have many projects in my eclipse and I downloaded all the files in SDK manager too. So I need to fix my existing ADT.

Comment: You can backup all those data and restore them after the installation

Comment: Before updating SDK pls do update ADT first else will suffer lot. thank u

Answer (score 0):

Do check this, Lint Error Checking will slow your ADT also seems to be occur error like what you got in a often situation..

- so Disable lint from Windows-> Preferences -> Android-> Lint Error Checking, Under
- Uncheck the two option in right hand side.

Be aware of what all your projects have JDK compliance.. set common JDK level.. mostly 1.6 based on need change to 1.7 for all projects..

- set JDk compliance level in properties of your project -> java compiler and select in right hand side..
- Always Check when importing any projects after import if its came up with a compatibility library or external library to be added like appcompat_v7

  Check in properties of project under android tab in library section if there is any missing files..

From all the above suggestions are not fulfilled your problem, then go ahead with a new fresh latest ADT Bundle with a fresh download of platforms of SDK.. it will solve most of the ADT problems..

Answer (score 0):

**Finally the problem solved** 
This problem occurred due to missing target SDK in project properties and because of the broken files in SDK manager.

What I did is:

1) I deleted all the broken images and Google api packages from the SDK manager and I re installed all the packages again,

2) Then I selected android 4.2 as the Android Build Target in the project properties.

Thanks all for the time and help.